# How to serialize C# class which will be sent to Java with SOAP

Tags: java, c#, serialization, soap, attributes

I have a problem and can't figure out how to solve it. I will appreciate all helps. In our project backend code was witten in C# and frontend in Java. For example, there is User class and I want to make this class Serializable. In C# there is attribute [Serializable()], but it doesn't make a sense. 
How can I make class User Serializable in a way that, it will remain Serializable in Java too.
Hope that I could express my issue properly. Thanks in advance for any helps.

```
[Serializable(), XmlRoot("User")]
[DataContract(Name = "User", Namespace = "urn:Rabita")]
public class User
{
    [XmlElement]
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
other fields and contructors
```

In java this class is generated in this way:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "lastLogin",
    "lastPasswordChange",
    "email",
    "otpTryCount",
    "loginFailCount",
    "loginCount",
    "lastFailDate",
    "otpType",
    "lastOtpFailDate",
    "lastName",
    "firstName",
    "pinCode",
    "phone",
    "userType",
    "accessType",
    "address",
    "documentName",
    "documentSerial",
    "documentNumber",
    "documentDate",
    "documentInstitution",
    "middleName",
    "gender",
    "isActive",
    "contractStatus",
    "userId"
})

public class User {

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "LastLogin", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar lastLogin;
    getters and constructors
```

Comment: When you use standard WCF, `[Serializable]` is ignored. It does the same thing as  `[DataContract]` so focus on that.

Comment: But it looks like Java already takes care of the Id / id adaptation. It is not clear what your problem is here.

Comment: Don't care about changing of fields's names. There is nno problem. 
The main issue is I want to make this class Serializable. I have 2 recommendations about it: 1. to make it through wsimport, 2. to write wrapper class for User. 
But I don't know how to do them

Comment: You already have the WCF standard data contrant, that takes care of the serialization  of everything to SOAP - You don't need to add the [Serializable] attribute.

Comment: The class already is serializable, even twice. So "make this class Serializable" needs clarification and specifications.

Comment: After wsimport generates classes in Java, class User is created as well. After authentification java throws exception that User class is not Serializable. How I can avoid this exception

Comment: That is Java, not my cup of tea. But I don't think you posted the relevant code.

Comment: I could do it as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658580/how-to-make-java-class-serializable-which-is-generated-by-wsdl