# How to make java class Serializable which is generated by wsdl

Tags: java, serialization, wsdl

In my project, classes are generated by wsdl. One of these classes is User class. This class must be Serializable. How can I change my pom.xml file for making User Serializable?
I can find example but can't apply it to my project
https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/make-serializable-jax-ws-clients-with-maven2/

Answer (score 2):

Finally I could find answer for my question. In our project we use org.apache.cxf plugin to generate classes. I created binding.xml file in resources folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:serializable uid="1337" />
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```

Then I referenced to this xml file from my pom.xml, for this I added

```
<bindingFiles>
    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding.xml</bindingFile>
</bindingFiles>
```

under wsdlOptions/wsdlOption tag. That's all

Comment: I can't believe your answer helped me!

Comment: Fəqan, təsadüfə bax aa ))

Comment: yadimda bu meseleni muzakire edirdik))