# How to store Tomcat sessions in Redis

Tags: java, tomcat, redis

I have to store Tomcat 8 sessions in Redis. I surfed in inthernet and found good  example:
https://github.com/chexagon/redis-session-manager
But it requires that classes must be serilizable. 
Is there another solving for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. There is project in github. I used it as it says in usage section:
https://github.com/chexagon/redis-session-manager

But this project requires that classes must be serilizable. I did it via plugin in pom.xml. If you want to see, here is it:
[How to make java class Serializable which is generated by wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658580/how-to-make-java-class-serializable-which-is-generated-by-wsdl)