# How to configure Spring sessions to work with Redis in xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-session

In our project we use xml configurations. My task is to store sessions in Redis. I looked for the solution in different sites but I couldn't find appropriate solving. Could you please give me the relevant way to solve problem or to say what I am doing wrongly?
Here is dependencies which I added for redis:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I added beans to dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean
class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory" p:host-name="localhost"
          p:port="6379"/>
```

My changes in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

These are all my configurations. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue. Firstly, I make classes serializable. For doing this, follow this post:
[How to make java class Serializable which is generated by wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658580/how-to-make-java-class-serializable-which-is-generated-by-wsdl)

Then I created redis-config.xml under webapp/WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="127.0.0.1"
          p:port="6379" p:usePool="true" p:database="0"/>

</beans>
```

Then I did some changes to web.xml. For storing sessions there must be springSessionRepositoryFilter with the class org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy. But I had this class in web.xml with another filter-name. In order for the program to work, springSessionRepositoryFilter should be written firstly:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Then I added /WEB-INF/redis-config.xml value to context-param, but it caused problem for log4j2. That is why I wrote context-param for log4j2 in the top.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/redis-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

That is all. Now sessions store in Redis

**EDIT**:
The code above was working only with local Redis. When I wrote remote Redis server it throws exception like this: Unable to configure Redis to keyspace notifications. For solving this, I changed my redis-config.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" p:configureRedisAction-ref="configureRedisAction" />
    <util:constant id="configureRedisAction"
            static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>
    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"
          p:port="6379" p:usePool="true" p:database="0" p:password="xxx"/>
</beans>
```

I forgot to mention that some new version of dependencies don't work with each other. The dependencies for redis should be as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```