# Using both WebApplicationInitializer and web.xml in spring mvc+spring security+spring session redis web application

Tags: spring, session, redis

I'm trying to implement Spring redis session in an existing Spring MVC (ver 5.1.6) application.  In web.xml we have ContextLoaderListener, DispatcherServlet and contextConfigLocation are all defined.

After required dependencies are included and suggested code changes are done, i'm getting below error:

***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!"}}***

As part of code changes i'm extending the class "AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer",(from Spring session core library) which internally implements WebApplicationInitializer.  Seems like that is trying to create another context and throwing the above error.  We cannot avoid extending this class, as this does the job of registering redisHttpSession to context.

Most of the examples available are all with spring boot.  So there they wouldn't have faced this issue.

Any solution, other than completely replacing web.xml and use only WebApplicationInitializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to provide an update.  Instead of extending AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer abtract class, i have taken a different approach by initializing bean RedisHttpSessionConfiguration thru XML bean definition.

This approach worked.

Followed the steps mentioned in the below thread;
[How to configure Spring sessions to work with Redis in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848870/how-to-configure-spring-sessions-to-work-with-redis-in-xml)

Along with that we need to serialize the cookie as well;

`@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("SESSIONID");
    serializer.setCookiePath("/");
    serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$");
    return serializer;
}`